# Taylor series and integration

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definite-integrals

Let $f$ be a twice continuously differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $0=t_0<t_1<\ldots < t_n=t$ be a partition of $[0,t]$. Then:

$$f(t)-f(0)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(t_{i+1})-f(t_i) \mbox{.}$$

From Taylor formula we have $$f(t)-f(0)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f'(t_i)(t_{i+1}-t_i)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f''(s_i)(t_{i+1}-t_i)^2 $$

where $s_i$ is some point between $t_i$ and $t_{i+1}$.

Now if we go with mesh of our partition to $0$, from fundamental theorem of calculus we know that the second sum goes to $0$. My question is why is it so?

Comment: I disagree on that "from fundamental theorem of calculus ...". What you are doing is exactly *proving* the fundamental theorem of calculus. You are not assuming it.

Comment: If you were to assume the fundamental theorem of calculus the proof that the second sum tends to $0$ could be much simpler. Just note that, as $\delta \to 0$, the first sum tends to $\int_0^t f'(s)\, ds=f(t)-f(0)$.

Comment: Very good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M = \sup_{s \in [0,t]} |f''(s)|$.

Suppose $t_{i+1}-t_i \le \delta$, then
$|\sum_k f''(s_k)(t_{k+1}-t_k)^2| \le M\sum_k (t_{k+1}-t_k)^2 \le M\delta \sum_k (t_{k+1}-t_k) = M\delta t$.

So given $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta < {1 \over Mt} \epsilon$.

Comment: Very good explanation, thank you very much!